# Athena table to query cloudTrail logs

Tags: hive, amazon-athena, amazon-cloudtrail

I created an Athena table in order to query cloudTrail logs.
I used AWS documentation to do that.
Attached the link to the documentation.

[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cloudtrail-logs.html](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

The table DDL is as follows:

```
  CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `cloudtrail_logs_pp`(
  `eventversion` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `useridentity` struct<type:string,principalid:string,arn:string,accountid:string,invokedby:string,accesskeyid:string,username:string,sessioncontext:struct<attributes:struct<mfaauthenticated:string,creationdate:string>,sessionissuer:struct<type:string,principalid:string,arn:string,accountid:string,username:string>,ec2roledelivery:string,webidfederationdata:map<string,string>>> COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `eventtime` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `eventsource` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `eventname` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `awsregion` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `sourceipaddress` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `useragent` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `errorcode` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `errormessage` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `requestparameters` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `responseelements` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `additionaleventdata` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `requestid` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `eventid` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `readonly` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `resources` array<struct<arn:string,accountid:string,type:string>> COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `eventtype` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `apiversion` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `recipientaccountid` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `serviceeventdetails` struct<eventrequestdetails:struct<dashboardid:string>,eventresponsedetails:struct<dashboarddetails:struct<dashboardname:string,dashboardid:string,analysisidlist:string,datasetidlist:string>>> COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `sharedeventid` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `vpcendpointid` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `tlsdetails` struct<tlsversion:string,ciphersuite:string,clientprovidedhostheader:string> COMMENT 'from deserializer')
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `timestamp` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'com.amazon.emr.cloudtrail.CloudTrailInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://xxxxxxxxxxxx-cloudtrail-logs/AWSLogs/xxxxxxxxxxxx/CloudTrail'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'projection.enabled'='true', 
  'projection.timestamp.format'='yyyy/MM/dd', 
  'projection.timestamp.interval'='1', 
  'projection.timestamp.interval.unit'='DAYS', 
  'projection.timestamp.range'='2021/01/01,NOW', 
  'projection.timestamp.type'='date', 
  'storage.location.template'='s3://xxxxxxxxxxxx-cloudtrail-logs/AWSLogs/xxxxxxxxxxxx/CloudTrail/yy-yyyy-y/${timestamp}', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1668349800')
```

When trying to query the table, I get an error as follows-
**HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: java.io.IOException: Start of Object expected**

I cannot figure out why.
Appriciate your advise.

Thanks!

I tried to query the table but got the error of HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: java.io.IOException: Start of Object expected

Comment: This will help you:- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/athena-hive-cursor-error/

Comment: Hi, unfortunately  I didn't find any information about this specific error. HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: java.io.IOException: Start of Object expected